# Tried streamlining w/ SDCols - got "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Tags: r, data.table

I have tried     searching stackoverflow and google to get answers to my question, but I couldn't find anything that applied closely enough for me to be able to apply it.  However, I'm very new to R, so it's likely that I may just need a little walking through it.

If I use the following code, it works just fine.

```
> dput(b)
structure(list(DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE = structure(c(1420070400, 
1420070400, 1420156800, 1420156800, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420329600, 
1420329600, 1420416000, 1420416000, 1420502400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), QUANTITY_REPORTING = c(235, 219, 232, 
219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 235), WTRECV = c(32.71, 32.71, 
20.19, 33.42, 21.61, 21.61, 21.61, 20.19, 21.61, 20.19, 24.2), 
LC12 = c(0, 0, 0, 94, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100), LC34 = c(0, 
100, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), LC5 = c(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 5, 0, 5, 0), HIS = c(25, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 60, 
0), UC = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), IBC = c(75, 
0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 35, 0)), .Names = c("DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE", 
"QUANTITY_REPORTING", "WTRECV", "LC12", "LC34", "LC5", "HIS", 
"UC", "IBC"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000005860788>)

library(data.table)

b_daily <- b[,.(d_tons=sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING)),by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE]
b_daily[,"d_WTRECV" := b[,.(d_WTRECV=sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*WTRECV)),by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE] [,.(round(d_WTRECV/d_tons, digits=2))]]
b_daily[,"d_LC12" := b[,.(d_LC12=sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*LC12)),by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE] [,.(round(d_LC12/d_tons, digits=2))]]
b_daily[,"d_LC34" := b[,.(d_LC34=sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*LC34)),by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE] [,.(round(d_LC34/d_tons, digits=2))]]
b_daily[,"d_LC5" := b[,.(d_LC5=sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*LC5)),by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE] [,.(round(d_LC5/d_tons, digits=2))]]
b_daily[,"d_HIS" := b[,.(d_HIS=sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*HIS)),by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE] [,.(round(d_HIS/d_tons, digits=2))]]
b_daily[,"d_UC" := b[,.(d_UC=sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*UC)),by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE] [,.(round(d_UC/d_tons, digits=2))]]
b_daily[,"d_IBC" := b[,.(d_IBC=sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*IBC)),by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE] [,.(round(d_IBC/d_tons, digits=2))]]
```

However, it seems very inelegant - I think that I should be able to do this using SD and SDcols. I tried the following, just as a test case:

```
b_daily2 <- b[,lapply(.SD, function (x) sum(x*b[,QUANTITY_REPORTING])/sum(b[,QUANTITY_REPORTING])), by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE, .SDcols=c("WTRECV")]  [,.(DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE,d_WTRECV=round(WTRECV, digits=2))]
```

The resulting numbers are a little off, and I get the following warning:

> "In x * MQD[, QUANTITY_REPORTING] :  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

I understand that this indicates recycling due to objects being different lengths...but I don't understand why or what. Any help would be much appreciated.  I apologize in advance if this is an elementary question.  Thank you.

Comment: You're right that this is a very basic and common problem. It would be much easier for you to pinpoint the source by going through the process of constructing a [mcve], I think. Fwiw, I think that is a warning message, not an error.

Comment: Your error refers to the fact that `x` and `MQD[,QUANTITY_REPORTING]` are not of the same length -- `x` is of length of the by group (one value for `DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE`) and `MQD[,QUANTITY_REPORTING]` is of length of the number of rows in `MDQ`.

Comment: @Frank I have updated my question to hopefully include a suitable example, and have changed the wording to "warning" instead of error.  Thank you for the edits.

Comment: @attitude_stool Thank you!  This makes a lot of sense - I see now how that could be.  Perhaps foolishly, I was hoping that "by" would also apply to `QUANTITY_REPORTING`. Is there a nice way to do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is arguably also inelegant, but at least fits into a single operation:

```
b_daily <- b[,{
    d_tons      = sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING)
    d_WTRECV    = round( sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*WTRECV)/d_tons, digits = 2 )

    list(d_tons = d_tons, d_WTRECV = d_WTRECV)
},by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE]
```

If there are many columns like `d_WTRECV`, with names stored in `cols = c("WTRECV",...)`, then...

```
cols    <- c("WTRECV","LC12","LC34","LC5","HIS","UC","IBC")
b_daily2 <- b[,{
    d_tons      = sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING)
    res         = lapply(mget(cols), function(x) 
                    round( sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*x)/d_tons, digits = 2 )
                  )

    c(list(d_tons = d_tons), setNames(res, paste0("d_",cols)))
},by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE]
```

A similar approach using `.SDcols` will be possible when [a bug related to it](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495) is fixed.

---

**Aside.** I think there is a feature request to allow for the first column to be used in computing the second, like

```
# NON-WORKING CODE:
b_daily <- b[,.(
    d_tons      = sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING),
    d_WTRECV    = round( sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*WTRECV) / d_tons, digits = 2)
),by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE]
```

This is how `mutate` in the dplyr package works. However, for your multicolumn case, dplyr is more of a hassle than a help, as far as I can figure.

By the way, you may want to wait on rounding. Usually, it's only a good idea for printing purposes and just unnecessarily worsens your later calculations.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply!  Your answer is definitely better than what I had!  However, I was really hoping to leverage `SDcols` or similar, as I have about 12 columns in addition to `WTRECV` that need the same treatment.  It seems like there must be a way, but perhaps it was just not meant to be. I will check out mutate {dplyr}, too.  Many thanks.

Comment: @user5402811 .SDcols is probably appropriate if you have 12 cols you want to treat similarly. It's hard to tell exactly what that means from your example, though. I'll show the `.SDcols` way; just a sec.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't use `.SDcols`, but that's just because of a current bug: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495 After that's fixed, `.SD` will go where `mget(cols)` is, roughly.

Comment: I actually feel better that it was a bug.  Thank you very much for the work around.  I updated my example to include more columns, so here is the final working solution for the whole kit:  `cols=c("WTRECV","LC12","LC34","LC5","HIS","UC","IBC")
b_daily2 <- b[,{
  d_tons      = sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING)
  res         = lapply(mget(cols), function(x) round( sum(QUANTITY_REPORTING*x)/d_tons, digits = 2 ))
  c(list(d_tons = d_tons), setNames(res, paste0("d_",cols)))
},by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE]`

Comment: @CJ9, the bug you refer to, [#495](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495) is now solved in devel v1.9.7. Either update to the devel version (see github wiki), or wait until v1.9.8 hits CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a particularly elegant way to do this. Here's a quick take.

```
sdc <- c("WTRECV", "LC12", "LC34", "LC5", "HIS", "UC", "IBC")
b2 <- copy(b)
b2[, (sdc) := lapply(.SD, "*", b2[, QUANTITY_REPORTING]), .SDcols=sdc]
b_daily <- b2[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE]
data.table(
  b_daily[, .(DUMP_END_SHIFT_DATE)],
  b_daily[, lapply(lapply(.SD, "/", b_daily[,QUANTITY_REPORTING]), round, 2), .SDcols=sdc]
)
```